# C# max() from string array not always biggest number

Tags: c#, arrays, string, max

This is a question around how the compiler/language deals with this.
Take the following code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter some numbers separated by ",");
var numbers = Console.ReadLine();
var splitNumber = numbers.Split(',');
var maxNumber = splitNumber.Max();
Console.WriteLine("highest is: " + maxNumber);
```

Entering a string such as "1,2,3,4,5" will output the 5 as the max number.
However, using "1,2,3,55,6" outputs 6. Whereas, "33,1,4,1" gives 4. Bizarrely, "33,1,2,3" gives 33.

I know there is a better/simpler/different way of doing this using a loop. I am totally missing something with how the compiler is treating these strings to determine the output. Can someone explain it? Or provide me a reference to look it up?

Comment: Note that `splitNumber` is an array of `String`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "max" string is the last string in lexicographical order, i.e. the order you would list them in a dictionary

You need to use e.g. int.Parse to convert your strings to a number type if you want the numeric maximum.

Comment: So far, this is the only answer explaining what's going on... Which was the question to begin with

Comment: Ahh!  That make sense!  Thanks

Answer (score 10):

In string comparison, `6 > 55` returns True.

Do this instead, Split the string into an array using [`Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2) Extension method and then use `MAX()` function which *Returns the maximum value in a generic sequence* available in LINQ

```
string x = "1,2,3,55,6";
var array = x.Split(',');
Console.WriteLine("highest is: " + array.Max(c => int.Parse(c)));
```

Output:

```
highest is: 55
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the number as ints from a list or array.

```
var <int> Numbers = new List<int>();
while(String had not ended)
{
    var splitNumber = (int) numbers.Split(',');
    Numbers.Add(splitNumner);
}        
var maxNumber = Numbers.Max();        
Console.WriteLine("highest is: " + maxNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, Convert the string array to an array of int using ConvertAll and then find the max

```
    Console.WriteLine("Enter some numbers separated by ");
    var numbers = Console.ReadLine();
    var splitNumber = numbers.Split(',');
    int[] myInts = Array.ConvertAll(splitNumber, int.Parse);
    var maxNumber = myInts.Max();
    Console.WriteLine("highest is: " + maxNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried compiling your code with same inputs. I have also getting the same output but i thing when u try to perform .Max() operation on a string array it is only comparing the first character of each entries in your second array.

If the input is **1,2,3,55,6** you are gonna get the output as **6** because when you compare all the numbers and there first digit **6** is the largest. But if you change the input to **1,2,3,75,6** now you are gonna get the output as **75** because **7** is the biggest first digit of all the numbers in the list.

```
string str = "1,2,3,75,6";
var splitNumber = str.Split(',');
var maxNumber = splitNumber.Max();
```

Like all the other answers u need to convert the string array into an integer array and then apply it.

Answer (score 1):

Ans for **how the compiler is treating these strings to determine the output?**:

As these are strings, string equality gets checked for it.
The compiler takes each string value and compares it to one by one char. It **deduces equality on the first occurrence of mismatch** (e.g. in 55 vs 6, 5 is less than 6, hence 55 is less than 6)

Answer (score 1):

**You can use this :**

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a series of number separated by comma and I will tell you which one is the biggest, cool!");
var input = Console.ReadLine().Split(',');
Console.WriteLine("Biggest is :" + input.Max(c => int.Parse(c)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
var splitNumber = numbers.Split(',').Select(c=>Convert.ToInt32(c)).Max();
Console.WriteLine("highest is: " + splitNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

change Var to Int64

```
Int64 maxNumber = Int64.Parse(splitNumber.Max());
```